# Mechanize and Nokogiri script

Tags: javascript, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to parse LinkedIn, and i met a problem..
I start to use Mechanize in ruby, for parsing and moving on the website.

My problem is, when i want to get the name of user, if i check the DOM with chrome, i can see the name of users, and my html balise...
The problem is, the html code, is in JS !

I let you see by yourself : http://pastebin.com/bZKA9Dr8

I need to click on the link where the class is "title" ... so the name of users ..

I tried some line like :

```
res = page.search('.bd')
```

but nothing is find ...

Thanks everyone, and sorry for my bad english .. ;)

Comment: FWIW: `mechanize` doesn't support javascript, and [linkedin](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/56347/~/linkedins-scraping-software-policy) doesn't want you scraping their site.

Comment: LinkedIn has an API. I'd recommend using it or you'll probably find your code will have a short useful life.

Comment: ok ... it's just for personal ... to learn mechanize ... It's pissed me off if i just stop trying ... how can i conturn this ?

Comment: Use a site that is a better target? Create your own using Sinatra and HAML to generate forms and test against it locally? Seriously, start simple then slowly ramp up the complexity. Or, is your intent to scrape LinkedIn and it's not really a learning exercise?